Responsibility before commandments?
The Midrash has Moses make the argument that God should not punish the Israelites for the Golden Calf, because He never told them not to engage in idolatry:

[Moses] said in front of [God]:  Master of the Universe, from where does Israel know that what they did [was wrong]? Did they not grow up in Egypt? And all people in Egypt are idolaters. And when You gave the Torah, You did not give it to them, and they were also not standing there, as it is stated: "And the people remained at a distance." [Exodus 20:18]  You only gave it to me, as it is stated: "And [God] said to Moses: “Ascend to the Lord.”" [Exodus 24:1]  And when You gave the [Ten Commandments], You did not give [them] to them. You did not say, אֲנִי ה' אֱלֹהֵיכֶם “I am the Lord, your God” [in the plural]; but rather אָנֹכִי ה' אֱלֹהֶיךָ “I am the Lord, your God” [in the singular]”. [Hence] You said it to me. Did I sin?
The Holy One, blessed be He, said to him, “By your life, you have spoken well. לִמַּדְתַּנִי – Limadtani! You have taught Me! From now on, I will say אֲנִי ה' אֱלֹהֵיכֶם “I am the Lord, your God [in the plural]”.
[Numbers Rabbah 19:33]

Earlier, at the time of the flood, we read:

The earth was filled with violent crime...  God saw the earth and beheld that it was corrupt...  God said to Noach: "The end of all flesh has come before Me. For the earth is filled with violent crime because of them, and so, I will destroy them with the earth." [Gen. 6:11-13]

In the spirit of Moses' argument, how should the people have known that they should not have engaged in violent crime?

I don't have a source putting these together, but with regards to shituf, I believe it was allowed before the giving of the Torah. Certainly with regard to the times before the flood, they were violating the 6 laws given to Adam, but even if not, with regards to violence, there is a famous R Nissim Gaon in Sefer Hamafteach that even gentiles should intuit logical mitzvot

I think there are different standards for בין אדם לחבירו

It was not logical to them, especially considering God had said, "The heart of man is evil from his birth".

Like @Shmosel says from an initial moral perspective, it is arguably clearly more wrong to be violent etc to a person than to think you are doing something wrong by believing in something.

Violent crime? You mean like murder? Have you ever learned the details of Kayin murdering his brother? It was pretty violent.

The question assumes that the kind of a crime committed could be defended by a righteous leader like Moshe. But it may not be true in view of https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.59a.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi

Even if something was not logical to them, at least they could try not to do to a victim what a criminal does.  If that did not work, they could learn from a righteous man Noah.

@shmosel -- Except that idolatry is the big bugaboo in the Talmud.  "Whoever rejects idolatry has fulfilled the entire Torah".
